# Retrieve and decode V-Chip data from an aired digital TV stream

Tags: video, streaming, video-capture, broadcasting, decoding

I'm trying to retrieve and decode V-chip data from my TV streams (NTSC/ATSC digital streams). Apparently these data are embedded somewhere in the stream itself, but I have no clue how they are embedded inside, if they are inside visual frames, or a different hidden channel.

How are they embedded in the stream? And how can I retireve these data? Is there a software tool to get those signals? I need to do this programmatically in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V-Chip is encoded in the Extended Data Services (XDS) that is part EIA-608 captions. How it is actually transported in/with the video depends the signal type and medium.

- **Analog:** Encoded with the captions on line 21 field 2.
- **SD SDI:** Probably also on line 21 field 2.
- **HD SDI:** On [line 9](https://www.smpte.org/sites/default/files/section.../2014_July_Closed_Captioning.pptx) of the HANC encoded as per SMPTE ST 334.
- **ATSC over the air:** In the [DTVCC transport channel](https://evertz.com/resources/eia_608_708_cc.pdf).
- **In a file:** [It depends on the wrapper](http://bento.cdn.pbs.org/hostedbento-prod/filer_public/2013/04/18/kudrle_cc_ancillarydata_v03.pdf).

It can be decoded in software. However, I don't know of any tools that aren't part of something larger, like transcoding, that can do it.

Comment: Looks like tools like `mediaInfo` can show it from a `.ts` file.